# In jsf, can i inject a sessionscope bean into an actionlistener?

Tags: jsf, javabeans, actionlistener, inject

In jsf, I want to inject a sessionscope bean into an actionlistener implementation. Can it be done?

Answer (score 2):

Like this:

```
YourBean testBean = (YourBean)FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext()
               .getSessionMap().get( "yourBean");
```

Comment: Can you please accept the answer? If it's working it - make it as V

Answer (score 0):

go through this..

http://www.oio.de/public/java/jsf-best-practices-javaserver-faces-session-tips.htm

or

```
    ELContext elContext = context.getELContext();
    context.getApplication().getExpressionFactory()
       .createValueExpression(elContext,"#{sessionScope.sessionValue}", String.class)
       .setValue(elContext, this.getSessionValue());
```

Comment: Thank you, guys. But shouldn't there be an annotation like @Inject or @EJB? After all, I have a Sessionscoped bean.